# returned json response is undefended django

Tags: javascript, json, django, jsonresponse

I'm trying to load my json response into my template but when i check it into my console returns `undefended` !

```
@login_required
def booking_detail_lists(request,id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Booking.objects.annotate(no_persons=Count('takes_by')),id=id)
    bookingvisitors = BookingVisitor.objects.filter(booking=obj) 
    doc = Document.objects.filter(booking=obj)
    documents = []
    for i in doc:
        documents.append({
            'source':i.docs.url
        })
    visitors = []
    for i in bookingvisitors:
        visitors.append({
           'full_name':i.visitor.full_name,
           'reason':i.reason,
           'check_in_vis':i.check_in_vis.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"),
           'check_out_vis':i.check_out_vis.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"),
           'admin':i.admin.username,
           'date':i.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
    })
    data = {
        'check_in':obj.check_in.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"),
        'check_out':obj.check_out.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"),
        'taker':obj.taker,
        'phone':obj.phone,
        'no_person':obj.no_persons,
        'id':obj.id,
        'takes_by':visitors,
        'images':documents,
    } 
    json_data = json.dumps(data)

    return render(request,'booking/booking_detail.html',{'data':json_data,'obj':obj,'id':obj.id})
```

urls.py

```
path('ajax/booking/<int:id>',booking_detail_lists , name='booking_detail_lists'),
```

my html template and ajax

```js
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"{%url 'booking:booking_detail_lists' id=2222 %}".replace(/2222/,parseInt({{id}})),
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data.data)

        }
    })
```

```html
<!--some html tags-->
```

but in the browser console returns `undefined`but when i just type {{data}} it show as i expected ?! thank you for your recommendation ..

Answer (score 0):

in the function `booking_detail_lists`, you are returning `render('<template_name>', {<Data for rendering in the template>})`...

When you're calling this URL with ajax, actually the template `booking_detail.html` is returned, which is not in the json format, but the html one.. And this response doesn't have property `data` (which you're calling with `data.data`)..

### JsonResponse

For the json response from django view, you need to use `JsonResponse` from `django.http`

- Change your function to include this

  ```py
  # ...Rest Imports
  from django.http import JsonResponse

  @login_required
  def booking_detail_lists(request, id):

    # ...Processing and generation of data

    return JsonResponse({'data':json_data,'obj':obj,'id':obj.id})
  ```